# Surface area of part of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2\,(z\ge 0)$ with special projection on the $xy$-plane

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The $xy$-projection of the part of the sphere we're looking at is the triangle with vertices $ O(0,0), A(R/\sqrt2),B(R/\sqrt2,R/\sqrt2)$.

My first instinct was to find a proper parameterization for the given surface $\Sigma$. I'm looking for a function $\vec{\varphi}$ such that $\Sigma = \vec{\varphi}(K)$, with $K$ the triangle as stated above.

I got $\vec{\varphi}: (x,y) \mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}), (x,y) \in K$. The norm of the normal vector is given by $$ \left\| \frac{\partial\vec{\varphi}}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial\vec{\varphi}}{\partial y} \right\| = \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}.$$

Now, $$ \operatorname{surf}(\Sigma)=\iint_K \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}dxdy = \int_0^{R/\sqrt2}dx\int_0^x\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}dy \\= R\int_0^{R/\sqrt2}\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}dx.$$

Substitution $x = R\sin t $: $$ R^2\int_0^{\pi/4}\arcsin(\tan t)\cos t dt.$$ Now I'm stuck. The problem states that I can use the fact that $\int_0^{\pi/4} \sqrt{2-\frac{1}{\cos^2t}} dt = \frac{\pi}{2}(\sqrt2-1).$ I don't see how to transform the integrandum I found to use this last one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use polar coordinates to solve $\iint_{K} \frac{R}{R^2 - x^2 - y^2} dx dy$ because you can see $K = P - L$, whit the region $P$ writing in terms of polar coordinates, and integral over $L$ could be simpler to find.